# Solving a laser's upper level ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1-y}{A} - \frac{y\times f(x)}{B}$

where y = y(x) and A,B are constants.

It is okay for the expression for $y$ to contain an integral of $f(x)$. I know that it is possible to do this integral analytically because I have seen a rough form of the solution in a paper but no information on how the solution is obtained was mentioned.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1-y$ can be solved to find $y = c_1e^{-x} + 1$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = y\times f(x)$ can be solved to find $y = c_2exp(\int_{1}^{x}f(x')dx')$

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange to form
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} + \left(\frac{1}{A} + \frac{f(x)}{B}\right)y = \frac{1}{A}
$$
this is now
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} + g(x)y = \frac{1}{A}
$$

which can be left in an integral form.